# Independence decomposition of $Y|X$?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables.

If $Y|X=x$ has a density function of $f(g(x), \sigma)$, where $g(x)$ represents the location of the distribution of $Y|X=x$, i.e. $E(Y|X=x) = g(x)$, and $\sigma$ is a constant not involving $x$, (for example $Y|X=x$ has a normal distribution and $f(g(x), \sigma)$ is the density function of $N(g(x), \sigma^2)$), is it correct that

- $(Y|X=x) - g(x)$ has a density function $f(0, \sigma)$?
- $Y|X - g(X)$ and $X$ are independent random variables? Therefore $Y|X - g(X)$ and $g(X)$ are independent random variables?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean $(Y|X=x)-g(x)$ or $Y|X=(x-g(x))$? I think it is the first but not sure.

Comment: @SergioParreiras: the first

Comment: What does $Y|X$ mean as a random variable if you do not specify a value of X?

Comment: @Henry: I learned that $Y|X - g(X)$ and $X$ are independent when $Y|X=x$ has a normal distribution $N(g(x), \sigma^2)$ from a lecture. Maybe I remember it wrongly about $Y|X$ (what about it is $Y|X=x$?

Comment: The question implicitly assumes that the pdf of $Y|X=x$ depends only on $x$ thru the location parameter, if this is the case then then answer of the first question is yes (but again this is built-in in your assumptions). For several distributions $x$ not only affects the first moment but also other moments...

Comment: Have Y|X and Y|X=x been formally defined in the lecture? Can you share their formal definition?

Comment: I am not sure how to formally define them. Maybe my notations are incorrect, but I heard them saying that $Y|X$ can be written as the sum of two independent random variables: $g(X)$ and the remaining.

Comment: @Mary I think that what you are really after is Y = E[Y|X] + (Y - E[Y|X]) which is an orthogonal decomposition of Y, meaning we can show that cov(E[Y|X], Y - E[Y|X]) = 0. Note that E[Y|X]=g(X), in your notation.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps.

**FACT 1**: Given two variables $X$ and $Y$, we have (in general):
$$ Y = \mathbb{E}\left[Y|X \right] + \left( Y- \mathbb{E}\left[Y|X \right]  \right),$$
and 
$$\mathrm{cov}\left(\mathbb{E}\left[Y|X \right], Y- \mathbb{E}\left[Y|X \right]  \right)  = 0. $$
This is true as:
$$ \mathrm{cov}\left(\mathbb{E}\left[Y|X \right], Y- \mathbb{E}\left[Y|X \right]  \right) = \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[Y|X \right] \left( Y- \mathbb{E}\left[Y|X \right]  \right)\right] $$
$$ = \mathbb{E}\left\{\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[Y|X \right] \left( Y- \mathbb{E}\left[Y|X \right]  \right)|X\right] \right\}= \mathbb{E}\left\{\mathbb{E}\left[Y|X \right]\mathbb{E}\left[  Y- \mathbb{E}\left[Y|X \right]  |X\right] \right\} = 0,$$ 
by definition of conditional expectation, law of iterated expectations, and taking out of conditional expectation what's already measurable.

**FACT 2**: Similarly, it can be proven (in general) that:
$$\mathrm{cov}\left(X, Y- \mathbb{E}\left[Y|X \right]  \right)  = 0. $$

If $X$ and $Y- \mathbb{E}\left[Y|X \right] $ are [(bivariate) normals](http://athenasc.com/Bivariate-Normal.pdf), then they are also independent (not just uncorrelated as per FACT 2). Moreover, under the same strong assumption, $\mathbb{E}\left[Y|X \right]$ and $Y- \mathbb{E}\left[Y|X \right] $ must also be independent, as $\mathbb{E}\left[Y|X \right]$ is just a measurable function of $X$ (no need to go through FACT 1 and bivariate normality arguments).